# Sinon stubs are not restored properly

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I am using mocha, chai and sinon to test my node-express code.

I am experiencing a weird issue, which looks like sinon cannot restore stubs and so in the next test I get the beknown error

```
Attempted to wrap <method1> which is already wrapped
```

Here is what I do

- I use `mocha-steps` instead of `it()` clause for my test cases, so
  that they run sequentially (I wanted to ensure it is not an async
  race condition)

  - I use sinon-test to clean up the stubs automatically, just in case I was doing something wrong

Here is a test case:

```
step('should do stuff', test(function () {

    const stub1 = sinon.stub(my_model1, 'method1');

    chai.request(server)
        .get('/endpoint')
        .send(body)
        .end(function (err, res) {
            stub1.restore();
            do_various_assertions(err, res);
        });
}));
```

And another one

```
step('should do other stuff', test(function () {

        const stub1 = sinon.stub(my_model1, 'method1');

        chai.request(server)
            .get('/endpoint')
            .send(slightly_different_body)
            .end(function (err, res) {
                stub1.restore();
                do_various_assertions(err, res);
            });
    }));
```

where I get the error above

```
Attempted to wrap <method1> which is already wrapped
```

If I comment out the stub in the second case works fine. But why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next step should know that previous step has completed, you need to call `done` function. In your example second step doesn't wait first one and `method1` isn't restored.

```
step('should do stuff', function (done) {

    const stub1 = sinon.stub(my_model1, 'method1');

    chai.request(server)
        .get('/endpoint')
        .send(body)
        .end(function (err, res) {
            stub1.restore();
            do_various_assertions(err, res);
            done();
        });
});
```